# I am scraping text from a table but the results is empty quotes ' '

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Below is 1 row of a table with 6 columns from the HTML Code

```
<tr>
  <td class="roster_jerseynum ">4</td>
  <td class="sidearm-table-player-name " data-sort="Vargas, Andres">
    <a href="/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/andres-vargas/2462">Andres 
    Vargas</a>
  </td>
  <td class="rp_position_short ">OH</td>
  <td class="height " data-sort="72">6-0</td>
  <td class="roster_class " data-sort="0">Fr.</td>
  <td class="hometownhighschool ">Bogota, Colombia / Lawrence Senior</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to scrape the player name column 2, below is HTML line.

```
<td class="sidearm-table-player-name " data-sort="Vargas, Andres">
  <a href="/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/andres-vargas/2462">Andres 
  Vargas</a>
</td>
```

Below is my code. The issue is the I cant scrape the name from `td (cell[1])`
The result of my code when I print List1 is only empty quotes ' ' and no names of players.
For List2, I am able to get the height without a problem.

I see in td for the names, there is additional `data-sort` and `a` tag.

Need the results as a list

Appreciate any Help.

```
for row in the_Table.findAll('tr'):
  cells=row.findAll('td')
  if len(cells)== 6:
    List1.append(cells[1].find(text=True).rstrip("\n"))
    List2.append(cells[3].find(text=True).rstrip("\n"))
```

Comment: The trouble with web scraping is that every page is different. It's difficult to answer this question without being able to look at the html. Can you include the code where you send the `GET` request and everything you do with it prior to the bit of code above? That would make this more replicable and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```py
for row in the_Table.findAll('tr'):
  cells=row.findAll('td')
  if len(cells)== 6:
    List1.append(' '.join(cells[1].findAll(text=True)).rstrip("\n"))
    List2.append(' '.join(cells[3].findAll(text=True)).rstrip("\n"))
```

`findAll()` returns a list, even if it finds only one item, so you can't use a string method on it until you convert it into a string. The `' '.join()` concatenates the members of the list into a string with whitespace as a delimiter.

Another option is to simply access the `text` attribute of each of the tags you're interested in:

```py
for row in the_Table.findAll('tr'):
  cells=row.findAll('td')
  if len(cells)== 6:
    List1.append(cells[1].text.rstrip("\n"))
    List2.append(cells[3].text.rstrip("\n"))
```

Comment: I tried it and it works great, however its not reading the rstrip for some reason. It showing the /n In front of the names, see below

Comment: ```Name Height
0 \nSnigdho Hasan 5-5
1 \nMichael Valentin 5-9
2 \nAndres Vargas 6-0
3 \nJasper Diangco 5-10
4 \nSayuj Zachariah 6-2
5 \nOmar Rezika 6-2
6 \nGabriel Pjatak 6-3
7 \nRyan Chabel 5-11
8 \nUtku Tanritanir 6-0```

Comment: Looks like you might need to use `lstrip()` as well. Or you could simply use `strip('\n')` and remove the offending newlines on both sides of each entry.

Comment: I used '''strip('\n')''' and it works. That's great. Awesome.

Comment: Btw how do I give Kudos to your profile or vote up your profile?

Comment: Glad it helped. Here's some [information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how to upvote/accept answers.